# Why I am unable to get output while copying data from file to array FileReader

Tags: java, io

I am unable to get the output while practicing a question on FileReader
As from my point of view it will show a[where i posted why no output particularly]

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileWriter1 
{

    public static void main(String s[])throws Exception
    {
        //char b='a';
        File f=new File("abc.txt"); //my file has a single character a 
        f.createNewFile();

        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        System.out.println(fr.read()); //1 
        char ch[]=new char[(int)(f.length())];
        fr.read(ch);//file data copied to array
        //fr.read(ch)
        for(char ch1:ch) 
        {
            System.out.println(ch1);   //2 why output is not coming here
        }
        System.out.println("********************"); //3
        FileReader fr1=new FileReader(f);
        int i=fr1.read();
        while(i!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println((char)i);  //4
            i=fr1.read();   
        }
        fr.close();
    }       
}
```

Output Shown:

```
97

*****
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the only character of the file here :

```
System.out.println(fr.read()); //1
```

That's what prints `97`.

which is why the following read has nothing to read :

```
fr.read(ch);
```

and your `ch[]` contains only the default value of `char` in all its indices, which explains the blank output line.

Comment: Okay But and what is the relation here between reading from a file and writing on a screen?

Comment: @mansikbchawla I don't understand the question. When you read from a file, you can store the data in a variable (as in `fr.read(ch);` or immediately write it to the screen, as in `System.out.println(fr.read());`. But once you read the data from the file (in one way or another), you can't read it again, unless to re-open the file and start from the beginning.